# Cannot negate hyphen in regex in golang

Tags: regex, go

I can't seem to negate a hyphen in regex in go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    reg := regexp.MustCompile(`[^\-][a-z]+`)
    match := reg.FindAllStringSubmatch("-string", -1)
    
    if len(match) > 0 {
        fmt.Println("Match")
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WvcFLVJpa1f)

It matches when it shouldn't, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You get a partial match as `[^\-]` can also match a char a-z so you match `string`. You can add anchors `^[^\-][a-z]+$`

Comment: I dont think you need to escape `-` in character class. make it `[^-] and try

Comment: Do you require that a string should not start with a hyphen? Or no hyphen anywhere in the text?

Answer (score 0):

`FindAllStringSubmatch` returns all matches of the regular expression in the given string, even if the match is only a substring. To make sure you match the entire string, you can match the start and end of the line with `^` and `$`.

You can see the issue by printing what the match is:

```golang
fmt.Println("Match:", match)
```

For your sample code, this prints:

```
Match: [[string]]
```

The `s` matches `[^\-]` and `tring` matches `[a-z]+`.

If you update your expression to match the start and end, `-string` no longer matches:

```golang
reg := regexp.MustCompile(`^[^\-][a-z]+$`)
```

See [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EWFzUbAwnG4).

---

I'll also note that if you don't need all matches of the given pattern, you can use `reg.FindString("-string")` and it returns the matching string. If you only need to know if there was a match or not, you can use `reg.MatchString("-string")`.

Also, I don't think you need the `\` in `[^\-]`, you can just do `[^-]`. I don't think the `\` hurts anything except readability (I could be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it. The problem is that the regex actually matches the string in your case, as mentioned in one of the comments.

```
s := "-string"
s1 := ".....-string"
```

as long as you have "string" anywhere it will match a substring without a `-`. Golang does not [support](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) regex lookbehind that would solve your issue.

If you do not want the first  element to be `-` you could do `^[^-][a-z]+` and it will do what you want.  Or if you expect the char before the dash to be a space or something other than a a-z char, then `\s[^-][a-z]+` would work, then  `-string` will not match as expected.

Also check what you are trying to do as there might be other better solutions to the problem than trying to do a regex.